# Anyone had luck with telnetlib.expect()?

Tags: python, telnetlib

I'm writing a library to support telnet'ing to a remote server and running apps.

Things are going swimmingly in establishing a connection, getting data back, parsing, etc. (at least as swimmingly as it can be for communicating with programs via a text interface).

One app will change the cursor if it enters properly, or leave the original cursor if it fails (I don't write the apps, I just have to use them.)

When said app starts up correctly, this works with no problem:

```
promptB = "hello(x)# "   # Yes, the space at the end is intentional
response = tn_conn.cmd("app_name\n", prompt=promptB)
```

I would like to use the prompt change (or lack of prompt change) to detect whether the program failed to start.  I figured this would be a golden opportunity to try telnetlib's expect(), since expect() allows one to pass a list of strings to match in the response.

I cannot, however, get this to work:

```
promptA = "hello(x)# "   # Yes, the space at the end is intentional
promptB = "hello> "      # Yes, the space at the end is intentional

tn_conn.write("app_name\n")
which_prompt, mo, response = self.tn_conn.expect([promptA, promptB], timeout=3)
```

The expect command always times out, whether to apps starts sucessfully or not.

which = "-1"

mo = None

response = "mumble mumble\r\r\n other stuff\r\n\r\nhello# "

The docs say that either a string or a regex object can be passed to expect (I'm passing a string), so am I missing something?  A look at the telnetlib code shows that its calling re.search(), not re.match(), so that wouldn't seem to be the issue.

Can anyone please offer suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**
Added parens to the prompt example to better illustrate why expect() was not working as expected.

Comment: If you're using a string it has to match exactly. You might have better luck with regex. Try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In previous attempts, I had pursued the regex option by placing `.*` at both ends of my search string, as well as doing a `re.compile()` to the search string before passing it/them to `.expect()`; all with no luck.

Thanks to jathanism's suggestion, I re-examined using regex, this time with the thought that `expect()` was, er... expecting 'regex' where I was thinking 'string'.

Sure enough, there were characters in my prompt string that expect was treating as regex symbols -- `()`'s to be exact.  Escaping the parens let `expect()` do its job.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget if you are using the regex in python you can always use the raw (`r'my string'`) method rather than adding in all the escapes; makes it more readable.

Answer (score 4):

I got something to work. Lookig for # or % or $ prompts. As for your prompts, make sure that special characters are escaped. ( ). Maybe escape everthing just to be sure.

```
idx, obj, response = tn_conn.expect("\#","\%","\$",3)
```